# Export an entire Access (accdb) database to csv/txt

Tags: csv, export, microsoft-access-2010

There is no option to export the whole db, rather Access only allows export of one table at a time.

I'm not familiar with any VB scripting so how would I go about doing this?

CSV must be exported with:

1. UTF-8 encoding
2. Comma delimited
3. Field names included in the first row

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function

`DoCmd.TransferText(TransferType, SpecificationName, TableName, FileName, HasFieldNames, HTMLTableName, CodePage)`

with the example

`DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Standard Output", "External Report", C:\Txtfiles\MyText.csv"`